# Redirect add to cart button woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

is it possible to redirect a link of the add to cart button depending on the product quantity?
The button works in ajax, which hook should I use?
I tried to use this code on the theme function, but it doesn't work:

```
function check_quantity() {
    $adult_number=$_POST['adult_number'];
    $child_number=$_POST['child_number'];
    $infant_number=$_POST['infant_number'];
    $total = $adult_number + $child_number + $infant_number;
    if ($total > 4){
        wp_redirect( get_home_url().'/viaggi-gruppo/');
        exit;
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'check_quantity');
```

How can I do?

Comment: I think you're too late... Well after headers are sent to use wp_ redirect

Comment: How can I do redirect or override add cart button action?